# Abstract builder

Tags: java, design-patterns, abstract, builder

So I have an abstract Transaction class, which has multiple implementations (Payment, File).

I would like to have a builder for the Transaction (abstract) + the implementor.

I did this:

```
public abstract class TransactionBuilder
{
    protected final Transaction transaction;
    
    public TransactionBuilder(Transaction transaction)
    {
        this.transaction = transaction;
    }
    
    public TransactionBuilder setSignature(byte[] signature)
    {
        this.transaction.setSignature(signature);
        return this;
    }
    
    public TransactionBuilder setPreviousHash(String previousHash)
    {
        this.transaction.setPreviousHash(previousHash);
        return this;
    }
    
    public abstract Transaction build();
}
```

Example for the PaymentBuilder class:

```
public class PaymentBuilder extends TransactionBuilder
{
    public PaymentBuilder(String from, String to, double amount)
    {
        super(new Payment(from, to, amount));
    }
    
    public PaymentBuilder addAmount(double amount)
    {
        ((Payment) this.transaction).amount += amount;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Payment build()
    {
        return (Payment) this.transaction;
    }
}
```

Every field has a getter/setter, Transaction:

```
public abstract class Transaction
{
    //Used for serialization
    private String type;
    
    private String previousTransactionHash;
    private String hash;
    private String signature;
    
    private String fromAddress;
    private String toAddress;
    
    private Instant timeStamp;
    
    public Transaction(String type, String from, String to)
    {
        this.type = type;
        this.fromAddress = from;
        this.toAddress = to;
        this.timeStamp = Instant.now();

        setHash();
    }
```

How I use:

```
Payment payment = new PaymentBuilder(from, to, amount)
                .setPreviousHash(previousHash)
                .build();
```

But when I call setSignature() I get "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Transaction to Payment" so I need to cast it to a Payment, how can I avoid that? Can I?

Comment: What is the signature of the `Transaction` class?

Comment: You could make your abstract builder generic, with the generic type being the type of transaction it produces.

Comment: @Sid Updated...

Comment: Awesome! How did I not think of it :) @khelwood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your abstract builder generic, with the generic type being the type of transaction it produces.

```
public abstract class TransactionBuilder<T extends Transaction> {
    ...
    public abstract T build();
}

public class PaymentBuilder extends TransactionBuilder<Payment> {
    @Override
    public Payment build() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @khelwood, I ended up making my abstract builder generic:

TransactionBuilder:

```
public abstract class TransactionBuilder<T extends Transaction>
{
    protected final T transaction;
    
    public TransactionBuilder(T transaction)
    {
        this.transaction = transaction;
    }
    
    public TransactionBuilder<T> setSignature(byte[] signature)
    {
        this.transaction.setSignature(signature);
        return this;
    }
    
    public TransactionBuilder<T> setPreviousHash(String previousHash)
    {
        this.transaction.setPreviousHash(previousHash);
        return this;
    }
    
    public abstract T build();
}
```

PaymentBuilder:

```
public class PaymentBuilder extends TransactionBuilder<Payment>
{
    public PaymentBuilder(String from, String to, double amount)
    {
        super(new Payment(from, to, amount));
    }

    public PaymentBuilder addAmount(double amount)
    {
        this.transaction.amount += amount;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Payment build()
    {
        return this.transaction;
    }
}
```